# How to make a multi page server control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I recently tried to create an ASP.Net server control. This server control should has at least two pages. One page for registration (Users can register) and one for asking questions. It is important to make it with ASP.Net Server Control.

`The plan is to make this server control and web designers can easily drag and drop this server control into ASP.Net WebForms or MVCs`  and set properties like back-color or header image in properties tab. I wonder if its possible to have two pages in a server control dll file with all events, viewstates and properties.

Please some one tell me how to create a second page in a server control `dll` file? And another question is how to move between those pages?

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you should go for MultiView or ASP:Wizard control ?

Comment: No. Multi view does not make a separate page.

Comment: Then What about ASP:Wizard control ? In this way you donnot need to transfer the data and saves your page count

Comment: That it what I will do if I couldn't make it right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/TabControl.aspx)  from codeproject.

Comment: Need more specific project. I need a separate page. It's just a page with tab control.